# Why is the output-layer of my neural network in MATLAB displaying zero?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to create a neural network in Matlab by using the `nntool` command.
It easily imports the inputs and the target values. But when I view the network it displays four layers:

1. Rows of inputs as 'Input'
2. Targets as 'Output'(which is actually of the same size as the rows of the       input)
3. 'Hidden layer'
4. 'Output layer'

What I do not understand is the output layer. For the tutorials I am seeing it is always the same size as the output; But no matter what number of target-values (output) or input values I give the 'Output layer' displays zero. For that matter I cannot get the desired result.

- My input matrix is `75x64` with minimum value `-0.63` and max `0.69`
- Target matrix is `1x64` with all `1`s so min and max are `1`
- Hidden layer is set to contain 15 neurons

[image: Here's how the neural network looks like]

Comment: Could you please describe the task you are trying to solve and provide the data?

Comment: I'm extracting SURF-Features from the corner points(numeric values detected in a foreground mask, for every corner point I get 64 SURF-Features(numeric values), so I get varying columns(depending on the corner points) and constant rows of size 64. Now this VaryingColumnsx64 matrix  is set as 'Input' for the neural network and for every row a target value of 1 is assigned, meaning a 1x64 matrix of 1's is assigned as  'Target'.

Comment: @Anton for detecting corners I use Harris-Corner Detector. I noticed by replacing the number of ones in the target value with some arbitrary value the output layer doesn't remain zero anymore.

Comment: What is the expected behavior of the neural network? What does it have to recognize? If all targets are set to 1, it would mean the output does not depend on input, does it?

Comment: @Anton I have an image consisting of cars on a road, I want to train the neural network to to be 1 for corner points of vehicle objects and then separately train it to be 0 for corner points of non-vehicle objects(trees buildings etc)

Comment: so when I give some corner points to the neural network it predicts me 1 for vehicle object corners and 0 for non-vehicle object corners

Comment: Exactly! You need to feed the network with enough sets of both positive and negative examples. So your target should consist of 0s and 1s (ideally 50/50). I think it will solve the problem.

Comment: @Anton the output payer is still zero, maybe the consecutive 1's and 0's are causing the problem

Comment: I could try to solve the problem if I had your data.

Comment: @Anton how do you upload an Excel file here? if not I'll email the Excel sheet to you

Comment: Sure, you can mail me to stackoverflow.coder(at)gmail.com

Comment: Ok, in your data I can see only one class of target. To train the network you need inputs corresponding to other classes (or to 1 other class) as well. The network will solve a classification problem, so it needs classes. Do you have inputs for trees, buildings an so on? Ideally the network should have seen as many input data as possible to be able to tell objects apart.

Comment: @Anton I gave inputs of vehicles and of the background as well setting target values for vehicles to be 1 and target values for the background to be 0, but it didnt make any effect